# Sonar SonarQube - SonarWay Findbugs - Missing classes message during sonarRunner task

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, analysis, sonar-runner

Environment: Java/Linux/Gradle 1.6/Jenkins latest

gradle clean build jacocoTestReport sonarRunner - working fine.

During the sonarRunner task, I see the following missing classes/lines when sonarRunner is trying to publish data to Sonar's own database (org.h2.jdbc..)

I see the following lines in the output. What can I do so that these missing items don't end up showing during the sonarRunner task/step.

```
11:15:47 11:15:47.076 INFO  - Findbugs output report: /production/jenkinsAKS/jobs/CAPersonSvc/workspace/build/sonar/findbugs-result.xml
11:15:55 The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
11:15:55   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
11:15:55   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
11:15:55   javax.crypto.SecretKey
11:15:55   javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec
11:15:55   javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory
11:15:55   javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec
11:15:55   javax.crypto.Cipher
11:15:55   javax.crypto.KeyGenerator
11:15:55   javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec
11:15:55   javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
11:15:55 11:15:55.245 INFO  - Execute Findbugs 2.0.1 done: 10991 ms
11:15:55 11:15:55.247 INFO  - Sensor FindbugsSensor done: 10994 ms
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you defined javax crypto & spring as dependencies in your build file?

Comment: No as build is working fine. This is coming during sonarRunner task

Comment: Are these classes used directly by your own code?

Comment: To answer Fabrice, no. we dont have any of those jars getting used during compile/test/war package operations. btw, JarFinder.com didn't show me a jar for javax.crypto.* except javax.crypto.Cipher To answer Pete, i dont think so.

Answer (score 0):

The missing classes are part of third party jar.

Please find the jar file name [from here](http://www.jarfinder.com/), then search in your local machine for the location of the jar files.

change in **build.gradle** with the jar file locations.

```
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        properties["sonar.libraries"] += "../Lib/for_spring.jar,../Lib/for_javax.jar"
    }
}
```

you can go through [this for reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/sonar_runner_plugin.html) : Chapter 36.5

If you **miss any runtime dependencies** to add you will get warning like this

```
19:57:21.394 WARN  - Class 'org/apache/commons/chain/Command' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
```

As you said, you didn't get this warning, so may be these are not runtime dependencies. I am not sure what dependencies are these, but you can try this one.

Comment: Gradle automatically configures `sonar.libraries` with the `compile` and `runtime` dependencies declared in the build script (and their transitive dependencies).

Comment: I'll try your hint Panther, but agree with Pete as well.

Comment: @ArunSangal : I have updated the answer, you can try this one out.